# svg <use> in Angular 2 Component seems to not work in IE11

Tags: svg, angular, angular2-template

Can anyone point me if svg `<use>` can work in IE 11 and how, inside of Angular 2 component?

It works fine in Chrome but does not work in IE for me.

I did include svg4everybody.js library but if I use this inside of a component template or template url, it does not work.

Please let me know what I should do. Thanks you ver much

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
     <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
     <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width='150' height='150' fill='pink' role='img'>
        <use xlink:href="app/sprites.svg#splitup"/>    
        </svg>
       `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/svg4everybody/svg4everybody.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this links says yes to IE11 https://css-tricks.com/examples/svg-for-everybody/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, It's not related to IE11, supports it SVG or no. Problem is that, at the point, when svg4everybody.js is loaded and svg4everybody() method is called, your template isn't rendered in the DOM.

So, you will need to call svg4everybody() from component's ngOnInit method.
See this: [Include External JavaScript Libraries In An Angular 2 TypeScript Project](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)

Comment: Thanks David, I will look into that and let you know if that's the case.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter when you initialize svg4everybody. Even at page load, it's fine. After initialization it will run in the background on an interval, so anything that gets added to the DOM afterwards will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

is not supported on IE10, IE11. But inline svg will however work.
Therefore you should rely on a module to import the symbol into the dom as a standalone svg.

You can use the module: https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg
With the `[forceEvalStyles]="true"` parameter for IE11.

This lib does not work with IE10, perhaps a reason is `innerHTML` not working on IE10 with SVG content.

Shims are available (I did not test the ng-inline-svg with them on IE10)

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/innersvg/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David Gabrichidze anwser, it's possible to add svg4everyone with npm install.

```
npm install --save svg4everybody
```

Add script in angular.json

```
...
"scripts": ["./node_modules/svg4everybody/dist/svg4everybody.js"]
...
```

And then use it like this in app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const svg4everybody: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ''
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // IE 11 external svg support
    svg4everybody();
  }
}
```